# HOW TO FIX: error: failed to push some refs to | Create Remote GitHub Repository?

Tags: flutter, github, repository, developer-tools

i cant push my projects to GitHub Repository it keeps telling me >>failed to push some refs
how to fix it?

Comment: Can you share the command you are using to push ?

Comment: the command that iam using is Git Bash

Comment: It's like the answer also contains the question.

Answer (score 0):

just open Git Bash Here on your desktop and follow this steps....write the following instructions:

1 ===> cd .....................copy your address

2 ===> git init

3 ===> run on your github project some thing like this ==> git remote add origin https://github.com/something/yourApp.git

4 ===> git remote

5 ===> run on your github project some thing like this ==> git push -u origin main

6 ===> git add -A

7 ===> git commit -m 'initial commit'

8 ===> run again ==> git push -u origin main ....but instead of main replace it with .....master so it will be like this

8 ===> git push -u origin master

and then login with your username and passowrd with the github account and it will push your project immediatly.